# detect bot using php

Tags: php, bots

I have a page called index.php and I have a script for detecting the bot, but it's not working properly. If the bot visits index.php, then I want welcome.php to be included.  If it's the original user, then welcome.php shouldn't be included.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
   function is_bot(){
   $botlist = array("Teoma", "alexa", "froogle", "Gigabot", "inktomi",
    "looksmart", "URL_Spider_SQL", "Firefly", "NationalDirectory",
    "Ask Jeeves", "TECNOSEEK", "InfoSeek", "WebFindBot", "girafabot",
    "crawler", "www.galaxy.com", "Googlebot", "Scooter", "Slurp",
    "msnbot", "appie", "FAST", "WebBug", "Spade", "ZyBorg", "rabaz",
    "Baiduspider", "Feedfetcher-Google", "TechnoratiSnoop", "Rankivabot",
    "Mediapartners-Google", "Sogou web spider", "WebAlta 
     Crawler","TweetmemeBot", "Butterfly", "Twitturls", "Me.dium", 
     "Twiceler", "Purebot", "facebookexternalhit",
    "Yandex", "CatchBot", "W3C_Validator", "Jigsaw","PostRank", 
    "Purebot", "Twitterbot",
    "Voyager", "zelist", "pingdom", "favicon");

   foreach($botlist as $bot){
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$bot)!==false)
    return true;    // Is a bot
    }
   return false;    // Not a bot
    }
```

Here is the main problem I'm getting - the following didn't work:

```
  if (is_bot()==true) {
session_destroy(); include_once('welcome.php'); exit; }
```

Next, I tried this, but it also didn't work:

```
  if (is_bot()) {
  session_destroy(); include_once('welcome.php'); exit; }
```

Please advise on any solutions for this situation.

Whenever i use like this it works

```
 if (is_bot())
 $isbot = 1;
 else
 $isbot = 0;
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages (e.g. `welcome.php` not found)?

Comment: What exactly "didn't work".  Did you get a PHP error message?  Did you get an unexpected result?  If so, what did you do want what result did you get?  Such as for a request with "Twitterbot" in the user agent, I expected true but got false.  Help us help you.

Comment: I would use stripos and check if the return value is > 0 or perhaps even >= 0. Have you thought about robots.txt already ?

Comment: @BareNakedCoder i havn't received any error that is the problem because the server is skipping the function

Comment: How are you testing it? Have you tried printing out `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to make sure the string you are searching for is in there?

Comment: @Andrew i visited the pingdom website and when i tested my website it is not detecting pingdom bot

Comment: I think that's as **your** UA string doesn't contain the "pingdom" string, use the Google Chrome dev tool (F12 --> CTRL-SHIFT-M --> UA box at the top) to alter your UA string to pretend to be somebody else

Comment: @Benjy1996 i have echo the UA value it showed 1 it means!! if i do like this then the bot is detected see -> if (is_bot())
 $isbot = 1;
else
 $isbot = 0;

Answer (score 5):

It's better to improve your is_bot function and use regular expression instead the long hectic search.

Something like below can be more usefull.

```
function is_bot(){
    preg_match('/bot|curl|spider|google|twitter^$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);

    return (empty($matches)) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: yes, but now google bot is saying website is unreachable

Comment: I typed it from phone you can modify names indide bot list like `google|twitteer` is not a correct bot name. Plus plz try replacing `empty($matches)` to `isset($matches[0])`. Still typing from phone. As I am about to sleep.

Comment: Sorry I thought website became unreachable. For that plz try improving it a little but hopefully it would ve helped u of achieving what u tried to do :) Time to sleep now as its 2:30AM here.

Comment: And do rememer to accep the solution if it resolved your problem or gave you a direction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain the issue is that the code **does** work (although is poorly optimised and formatted - @[Imran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34232356/5663450)'s solution is much cleaner) but you are testing it incorrectly.

**Your** UA string doesn't contain the "bot" string - you are not a server. Use the Google Chrome dev tool, like so;

1. <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
3. UA box at the top
   and alter your UA string to pretend to be somebody else e.g. "Googlebot" and then test it.

Just by visiting a website and navigating back to your's does not imitate a 'bot request' from that website, it is still just you!

Comment: you've repeated OP's code. the `if()` has no opening `{`, so the `}` after the true return is terminating the foreach. count the braces. you've got 2x`{` and 3x`}` - e.g. a syntax error.

Comment: yeah. op's bad indenting threw me off as well.

Comment: @Benjy1996 how to include welcome.php after checking bot?

Comment: Either of the two original ways you did it in your post, I don't think that was the issue
`if (is_bot()) {
      session_destroy();
      include_once('welcome.php');
      exit;
}` should work fine

Comment: Try @Imran 's solution

Comment: Actually I think my code makes no difference to op's

Comment: hehe, still cleaner than op's :)

Answer (score 0):

The below code is **100% working on my website**.

```
function isBotDetected() {

    if ( preg_match('/abacho|accona|AddThis|AdsBot|ahoy|AhrefsBot|AISearchBot|alexa|altavista|anthill|appie|applebot|arale|araneo|AraybOt|ariadne|arks|aspseek|ATN_Worldwide|Atomz|baiduspider|baidu|bbot|bingbot|bing|Bjaaland|BlackWidow|BotLink|bot|boxseabot|bspider|calif|CCBot|ChinaClaw|christcrawler|CMC\/0\.01|combine|confuzzledbot|contaxe|CoolBot|cosmos|crawler|crawlpaper|crawl|curl|cusco|cyberspyder|cydralspider|dataprovider|digger|DIIbot|DotBot|downloadexpress|DragonBot|DuckDuckBot|dwcp|EasouSpider|ebiness|ecollector|elfinbot|esculapio|ESI|esther|eStyle|Ezooms|facebookexternalhit|facebook|facebot|fastcrawler|FatBot|FDSE|FELIX IDE|fetch|fido|find|Firefly|fouineur|Freecrawl|froogle|gammaSpider|gazz|gcreep|geona|Getterrobo-Plus|get|girafabot|golem|googlebot|\-google|grabber|GrabNet|griffon|Gromit|gulliver|gulper|hambot|havIndex|hotwired|htdig|HTTrack|ia_archiver|iajabot|IDBot|Informant|InfoSeek|InfoSpiders|INGRID\/0\.1|inktomi|inspectorwww|Internet Cruiser Robot|irobot|Iron33|JBot|jcrawler|Jeeves|jobo|KDD\-Explorer|KIT\-Fireball|ko_yappo_robot|label\-grabber|larbin|legs|libwww-perl|linkedin|Linkidator|linkwalker|Lockon|logo_gif_crawler|Lycos|m2e|majesticsEO|marvin|mattie|mediafox|mediapartners|MerzScope|MindCrawler|MJ12bot|mod_pagespeed|moget|Motor|msnbot|muncher|muninn|MuscatFerret|MwdSearch|NationalDirectory|naverbot|NEC\-MeshExplorer|NetcraftSurveyAgent|NetScoop|NetSeer|newscan\-online|nil|none|Nutch|ObjectsSearch|Occam|openstat.ru\/Bot|packrat|pageboy|ParaSite|patric|pegasus|perlcrawler|phpdig|piltdownman|Pimptrain|pingdom|pinterest|pjspider|PlumtreeWebAccessor|PortalBSpider|psbot|rambler|Raven|RHCS|RixBot|roadrunner|Robbie|robi|RoboCrawl|robofox|Scooter|Scrubby|Search\-AU|searchprocess|search|SemrushBot|Senrigan|seznambot|Shagseeker|sharp\-info\-agent|sift|SimBot|Site Valet|SiteSucker|skymob|SLCrawler\/2\.0|slurp|snooper|solbot|speedy|spider_monkey|SpiderBot\/1\.0|spiderline|spider|suke|tach_bw|TechBOT|TechnoratiSnoop|templeton|teoma|titin|topiclink|twitterbot|twitter|UdmSearch|Ukonline|UnwindFetchor|URL_Spider_SQL|urlck|urlresolver|Valkyrie libwww\-perl|verticrawl|Victoria|void\-bot|Voyager|VWbot_K|wapspider|WebBandit\/1\.0|webcatcher|WebCopier|WebFindBot|WebLeacher|WebMechanic|WebMoose|webquest|webreaper|webspider|webs|WebWalker|WebZip|wget|whowhere|winona|wlm|WOLP|woriobot|WWWC|XGET|xing|yahoo|YandexBot|YandexMobileBot|yandex|yeti|Zeus/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
    ) {
        return true; // 'Above given bots detected'
    }

    return false;

} // End :: isBotDetected()
```